# fullcalendar whole view broke after div rotation

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar library for different kind of calendar view but we are having some issue when we load fullcalendar view after rotating the parent div to 90 degree right. in this scenario whole UI just broke up. is there any way so that we can achieve the same view even after rotating the parent div?

## Html code

```
   <html>
      <body id="body">
        <div id=calendar>
        <div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

## java script code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
      var bodyElement = document.getElementById("body");  
      bodyElement.style.transform='rotate(90deg)';                          
      setTimeout(drawCalendar, 1000);       
        
      function drawCalendar() {
         var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
         var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
               //options
         });
         calendar.render();
      }             
    });
```

Comment: After rotation, try running calendar.render() again to force it to redraw. Provide a [mre] of the issue in your question if you require further help (see also [ask] for guidance on what to include in your questions).

Comment: @ADyson i am using same flow..like rotate body element by 90 degree right and then call calendar.render(). Anyways i will add some sort of example that i am doing.

Comment: @ADyson I added all required details in my question. let me know if that would be helpful. don't know why this question got closed

Comment: It got closed before you added more info. I've already voted to re-open it. Be patient

Comment: You can't reproduce the problem easily from the question, because FullCalendar is a paid product.  I was able to successfully rotate the demo calendar on this page https://fullcalendar.io/demos by applying the same css to the demos___main element, so I guess it should work.  Maybe try applying the rotation after the calendar has rendered?

Comment: @James fullcalendar is mostly not paid, only the "resource" functionality is paid, and even then some people can get free licenses. It's easy to put fullcalendar in a code pen demo, for example

Comment: I took the above code and added the fullcalendar component, I added a margin to the body element but that's it - https://jsfiddle.net/57u4xLms/  Seems to work?  Not sure if it illustrates a problem.

Comment: @James, i will look into it and update here.

Comment: @ADyson, loading calendar 1st and then rotate is working in my case also but that is not feasible i guess because in real time we are updating the data and view so whenever we call render next time with next set of data then it will break again.

Comment: Once we add the CSS to James' example it becomes clear that it doesn't even enjoy the first rotation: https://jsfiddle.net/pgywsvh6/ . I think fundamentally somehow fullCalendar is not compatible with your idea. Not sure why you want to have the calendar sideways or upside down anyway though?!